# Symfony 4 : localized twig date forms

Tags: twig, symfony4

I was used to redefine the date_widget in a form/fields.html.twig file in Symfony 2 and 3 to force twig generated date choices to french order : day month year with this code :

```
{%- block date_widget -%}


  {%- if widget == 'single_text' -%}
        {{ block('form_widget_simple') }}
    {%- else -%}
        <div {{ block('widget_container_attributes') }}>
            {{- date_pattern|replace({
                '{{ year }}':  form_widget(form.year),
                '{{ month }}': form_widget(form.day),
                '{{ day }}':   form_widget(form.month),
            })|raw -}}
        </div>
    {%- endif -%}

{%- endblock date_widget -%}
```

Now with Symfony 4.4, I get automagicaly this french order in my Linux station. But in the production server, the order is again US standard : month day year. If I redefine this order with the code sample above, I get french order in production server, but US order in my station.

Both systems have the php.ini defining **date.timezone = 'Europe/Paris'**

Also, the months names are in french and in english according to the month position. So where does TWIG search the locale to define this order?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I've found the trick : Twig uses the php-intl extension to localize. This extension was missing in my production server.